# Trying to create custom validation in laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm trying to create a custom validation rule within laravel 4 and am struggling to get it to work or understand what I'm doing.

Currently - when I try to submit a form and validate it i get the following in my browser:

```
/**/
```

Which I'm taking as something is broken!

I have created a class in `app/validators/customValidate.php`

```
class CustomValidate extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
{

public function uniqueMailchimp($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $mailchimp = MailchimpWrapper::lists()
    ->memberInfo(
    'xxxxxxx',
    array('emails'=>array(
        'email'=>$value
        )
    ));

    //dd($$mailchimp['success_count']);

    return ($mailchimp['success_count'] > 0 ? false : true );
}
```

I have run composer dump-autload

In my controller I am doing the following:

```
$rules = array(
            'email' =>'email|uniqueMailchimp',

        );

    $messages = array(
            'uniqueMailchimp'=>'The email provided has already been used.'
        );

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);

}
```

I am then checking for a valid form with:

```
if($validator->passes()) {
    # code
}
```

if validation fails the controller should redirect to the view:

```
return Redirect::route('members.create')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->with('errMessage', $message);
```

I've probably missed a step. I've seen posts about registering the rule in global.php but I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right - you need to register your rule with the validator. In any bootstrap-like file (a service provider is the best candidate if you have one, else `app/start/global.php` is good, and routes.php wouldn't be crazy either) you need the following code:

```
Validator::extend('foo', 'CustomValidate@uniqueMailchimp');
```

However, if you take a look at [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules) you'll see that you don't need a whole class for this - you can just do it as a closure. A class is useful if you want the automatic IoC DI carried out for you though (although you don't appear to use that in your validator).